# Finding truth value through the division of variables in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm having a hard time understanding the logic behind my lecturer's predicate statement: 
$∀x ∈ \{1,2,3\}\; ∃y ∈ \{4,5,6,7\} y|x$

We have to find the truth value from the above statement. Ignore the fact that I used 1,2,3  etc. but please read my reasoning below and tell me the best way to go about solving this.

I am assuming that the `|` means division in this scenario. When I first saw this statement, here is my thinking and the problem that I encountered:

I did a table that calculates y divided by x and got a mix of integers [see working out on paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEIFB.jpg)

The predicate statement, do however, state that:
some of the y values divides all of the x values or
all of the x values are divisible by some of the y values
But I am not sure what to look for here.

What does finding the truth value from this statement even mean? All I yielded were some integers from the calculation.

Comment: I think the proper use of $y|x$ is $y$ divides $x$, not $y$ is divisible by $x.$ So for example $2|4.$

Comment: [Usually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Some_common_primitive_recursive_functions) $a|b$ means "$a$ divides $b$"

Comment: Thus, the formula reads "for every $x$ there is an $y$ such that $y$ divides $x$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the quantifiers is important here.

$\forall x \in [1,2,3] \exists y \in [4,5,6,7] y|x$ is read as "for every $x$, I can pick a $y$ such that $x$ is divisible by $y$." So we pick the $y$ after we choose $x.$

However, $\exists y \in [4,5,6,7] \forall x \in [1,2,3] y|x$ is read as "there is a $y$ that I can pick such that for every $x$ you could pick, $x$ is divisible by $y$." So the $x$ is chosen after the $y.$